# Multiple single lists within the same index

Tags: python

I am facing this problem after downloading data from a certain API, the data is downloaded in json format.

```
for i in range(color_id):
            testing1= [colors_full_list[i]['name']]
            print(testing1)
```

above is my code and it results in a list of strings.

```
(Ie: ['orange'] 
      ['apple'] 
      ['pear'] )
```

When I try to index it -> testing1[0], the above appears, but then I try to index it like testing1[1], there would be some error that it's out of range.

```
        `len(testing1)`
```

results in 1,1,1.

I want my end result to be

```
      `['orange' , 'apple', 'pear']`
```

and have tried multiple solutions i could found on the web but still couldn't get it to work.

please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try simply appending them to list.
So, your code goes like:

```
array_required = []
for i in range(color_id):
     array_required.append(colors_full_list[i]['name'])
```

This will give you expected output.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is overriding the variable for every iteration of loop, so after completion of the for loop you are left with only one item in

> testing1

What you want to do is to append the elements to a list which can easily achieved by declaring an empty list outside the for loop and then call append() function on the list for every element.

```
result = []
for i in range(color_id):
    result.append(colors_full_list[i]['name'])
print(result)
```

This will give you the desired result

> ['orange' , 'apple', 'pear']

Comment: Thank you. But it ended up with multiple entries:

'''
['orange']
['orange' ,' apple']
['orange', 'apple', 'pear']
'''
The above was repeated 5 times. (as the color_id value is 5). Why is that so?

Comment: can you give an example of the data present in the colors_full_list, so that i can get an idea of how the data is structured and will be able to give you a better solution. @pamut3

Comment: It's okay! It sounds strange but I got it right after running a few times. Thanks!